# Deploy image to AWS Elastic Beanstalk from private Docker repo

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to pull Docker image from its private repo and deploy it on AWS Elastic Beanstalk with the help of Dockerrun.aws.json packed in zip. Its content is

```
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
    "Authentication": {
        "Bucket": "my-bucket",
        "Key": "docker/.dockercfg"
    },
    "Image": {
        "Name": "namespace/repo:tag",
        "Update": "true"
    },
    "Ports": [
        {
            "ContainerPort": "8080"
        }
    ]
}
```

Where "my-bucket" is my bucket's name on s3, which uses the same location as my BS environment. Configuration that's set in key is the result of

```
$ docker login
```

invoked in docker2boot app's terminal. Then it's copied to folder "docker" in "my-bucket". The image exists for sure.
After that I upload .zip with dockerrun file to EB and on deploy I get

```
Activity execution failed, because: WARNING: Invalid auth configuration file
```

What am I missing? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: can you try and change "docker/.dockercfg" to something less tricky? how about "myapp.dockercfg"? EBS is infamous for its intolerance towards data validation.

Comment: thanks for your comment, @Tal, but still no luck and there's the same issue

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Docker has updated the configuration file path from `~/.dockercfg` to `~/.docker/config.json`. They also have leveraged this opportunity to do a breaking change to the configuration file format.

AWS however still expects the former format, the one used in `~/.dockercfg` ([see the file name in their documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_image.html#create_deploy_docker_image_dockerrun)):

```
{
  "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
    "auth": "__auth__",
    "email": "__email__"
  }
}
```

Which is incompatible with the new format used in `~/.docker/config.json`:

```
{
    "auths": {
        "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
            "auth": "__auth__",
            "email": "__email__"
        }
    }
}
```

They are pretty similar though. So if your version of Docker generates the new format, just strip the `auths` line and its corresponding curly brace and you are good to go.

Comment: I made a post that should fill in the gaps in the AWS docs and videos: [Deploy Private Docker to Elastic Beanstalk](http://thequietlattice.com/docker/aws/elasticbeanstalk/2015/12/18/deploy-private-docker-to-elb.html)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Docker version, this file is saved as either ***~/.dockercfg*** or ***~/.docker/config.json**

> cat ~/.docker/config.json

Output:

```json
{
  "auths": {
    "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
      "auth": "zq212MzEXAMPLE7o6T25Dk0i"
    }
  }
}
```

***Important:***

Newer versions of Docker create a configuration file as shown above with ***an outer auths object***. ***The Amazon ECS agent only supports dockercfg authentication data that is in the below format, without the auths object***. If you have the jq utility installed, you can extract this data with the following command:

> cat ~/.docker/config.json | jq .auths

Output:

```json
{
  "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
    "auth": "zq212MzEXAMPLE7o6T25Dk0i",
    "email": "email@example.com"
  }
}
```

1. Create a file called `my-dockercfg` using the above content.
2. Upload the file into the S3 bucket with the specified key(`my-dockercfg`) in the Dockerrun.aws.json file.

```json
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "authentication": {
    "bucket": "elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-618148269374",
    "key": "my-dockercfg"
  }
}
```