# Elastic Beanstalk fails to authenticate with Dockerhub private repository despite providing credentials in Dockerrun.aws.json

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ecs

I have deployed two containers on an AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance, one of which uses a Dockerhub private repository. However, Elastic Beanstalk encounters an authentication issue when attempting to pull the Dockerhub image.

According to the Elastic Beanstalk documentation, I need to add an "authentication" key to the Dockerrun.aws.json file with the S3 bucket and key. I've done this, but it doesn't seem to work. The image pull still fails, and the generated task_definition.json doesn't have any credentials listed.

**Error message from /var/log/ecs/ecs-agent.log:**
[CannotPullContainerError] Error response from daemon: pull access denied for {username}/{repo}, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied" module=docker_client.go

**Environment:**

AWS Elastic Beanstalk version: ECS running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.2.6

**[.dockercfg]**

```
{
    "auths": {
        "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
            "auth": "base64encoded-username-password",
            "email": "email"
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried:

```
{
    "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
        "auth": "my-auth-info",
        "email": "myemail@gmail.com"
    }
}
```

**[Dockerrun.aws.json]**

```
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
    "authentication": {
        "bucket": "my-bucket-name",
        "key": ".dockercfg"
    },
    "volumes": [
      {
        "name": "php-app",
        "host": {
          "sourcePath": "/var/app/current/php-app"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "nginx-proxy-conf",
        "host": {
          "sourcePath": "/var/app/current/proxy/conf.d"
        }
      }
    ],
    "containerDefinitions": [
      {
        "name": "php-app",
        "image": "docker.io/{my-username}/{my-repo}:{my-tag}",
        "essential": true,
        "memory": 128,
        "mountPoints": [
          {
            "sourceVolume": "php-app",
            "containerPath": "/var/www/html",
            "readOnly": true
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "nginx-proxy",
        "image": "nginx:stable-alpine",
        "essential": true,
        "memory": 128,
        "portMappings": [
          {
            "hostPort": 80,
            "containerPort": 80
          }
        ],
        "links": [
          "php-app"
        ],
        "mountPoints": [
          {
            "sourceVolume": "php-app",
            "containerPath": "/var/www/html",
            "readOnly": true
          },
          {
            "sourceVolume": "nginx-proxy-conf",
            "containerPath": "/etc/nginx/conf.d",
            "readOnly": true
          },
          {
            "sourceVolume": "awseb-logs-nginx-proxy",
            "containerPath": "/var/log/nginx"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

**Troubleshooting steps I've already tried:**

1. Added AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess policy to the aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role associated with my ec2 instance
2. tried a different format for dockercfg like found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31395904/deploy-image-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk-from-private-docker-repo):

```
{
    "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
        "auth": "my-auth-info",
        "email": "myemail@gmail.com"
    }
}
```

3. tried renaming it to config.json
4. Sshed into the instance and was able to download the file successfully.